# Verbs for scores or results coming out?

Tags: word-choice

I want to describe a condition that my grades or experiment results come out.

I am not sure if come out is precise to express my question. I want to state that a

result finally shows up, such as

`I receive a email of my test score`, 
or

```
I eventually get the experiment data after a three-day science experiment.
```

I am also interested in both colloquial and formal ways to describe it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would often think scores/grades are being *released* or *announced*, but that doesn't seem like the same thing I'd say for data being completed (I'm assuming you waited 3 days for an experiment to complete, not that it took 3 days to get results from some experiment completed earlier than that).

Comment: CEM, thank you for the reply. Now I can understand that I should say my score is released or announced. About the experiment, it is a computer simulation experiment. The data is not gradually collected such as that cows of treatment and experiment groups are taken blood each hour for three days. However, the data suddenly shows up after the three-day experiment. Can I still say the my data is completed or completes? Does complete imply that it is collected gradually?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think one would say that the data was completed.  To be more precise you could say your *data gather* or *data collection* has been completed if that helps.  Also, complete does not imply gradual collection, complete would mean that all the collection has finished.

Answer (score 2):

If a person is the one who is sending you the data or scores, you could say they are being *released* or *reported*.  If they are releasing the data in a more formal or public fashion (e.g. posting test scores on a bulletin board), you could also say that the test results are being *published*.

If it is not a person performing the action, then you may wish to use the passive voice and a more ambivalent verb, such as "the data **became available** after three days."